# How to use React ref in MobX?

Tags: reactjs

My code like this

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Layout ref={element => this.ipDetailDOM = element} id="ip-detail">
            ...
        </layout>
      </div>
    )
}
```

But `this.ipDetailDOM` return an `Adapter` Object.

```
Adapter {props: {…}, context: {…}, refs: {…}, updater: {…}, _reactInternalFiber: FiberNode, …}
```

I do not know to use it?

Comment: How does the layout component look like, also , it it created using an HOC

Comment: How did you create the `ref`? using `createRef()`?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri what`s HOC, the problem i think maybe i am using mobx.

Comment: @Abinthaha i am using ref = { dom => this.dom = dom } this way

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ReactDOM.findDOMNode](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode)(this.ipDetailDOM) to access the underlying DOM node.

Here is working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/n453w61j5p

Comment: @ruoru. No, it works as suggested. See the demo I attached.